# Limit of product of a diverging function and a function going to 0

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I just want to verify something :

Say you have $f(x)$, an increasing function which goes to infinity as $x$ goes to infinity, and $g(x)$, a decreasing function for which the limit will be $0$ when x goes to infinity.

Then, $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)g(x)$ can only be infinity, or $0$, depending on which function converges "faster".  So if I can find a way to show that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)g(x)$ is finite, then it must be $0$ since $g(x)$'s limit is $0$.  Am I right?  I would need that property to prove something more important, and I think I remember seeing something like that before, but want to verify.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Then $f(x)g(x)=1$, which contradicts your claim.

You might want to read more about indeterminate form and L'hopital's rule.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I should have realized that.  Just a tired idea I guess.  Can't use l'hopital since the functions in my product don't have a functional form (at least not known).